# Unable to Select Table Rows in PrimeFaces Using RadioButtons

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to develop a web application using a PrimeFaces data table.  I am having difficulty getting the object that corresponds to the selected row.  Whenever I do that, a null value gets selected.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<p:dataTable id="presTable" var="pres" value="#{presBean.presentations}"
  rows="10" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="85%" 
  selection="#{presBean.selectedPres}" rowKey="#{pres.id}" paginator="true" 
  paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,100" widgetVar="presTable" filteredValue="#{presBean.filteredPres}" selectionMode="single">

    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">                                                                        
        <p:commandButton id="updateButton" process="presTable" value="Update" action="#{presBean.printSelectedPres()}"/>                                                               
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Java backing bean:

```
public Presentation getSelectedPres() {
    System.out.println("Returning selected presentation: " + selectedPres);
    return selectedPres;
}

public void setSelectedPres(Presentation selectedPres) {
    System.out.println("Setting selected presentation to " + selectedPres);
    this.selectedPres = selectedPres;
}

public void printSelectedPres() {
    System.out.println("Printing list of checked presentations:");
    System.out.println(selectedPres);
}
```

Comment: Is your `p:dataTable` wrapped by an `h:form` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with seletionMode=single

```
<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
```

you can find sample for radio button here : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: I have h:form and added selectionMode. Still I am seeing null value.I see the rows and when I select a radio button I am seeing null in System.out.println(selectedPres);